# How can I access a local file from a Java webservice deployed on a server?

Tags: java, web-services, file

I have created a Java webservice that performs a specified function on a chosen file. I will have to deploy the service to the server and will be calling the url to thr service from my Java code. Now, the file on which the function is to be performed has to be sent in post header as a parameter to the webservice. How can I access this file path from the server? If I simply send the path to that file (eg C:/folder/file.pdf) as a parameter to the webservice, will it work? If not, how can that be achieved?

I need to know the answer before the service is deployed.

The webclient is as follows:

```
WebTarget webTarget = clientobj.target("http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/method1/Name1");
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
            formData.add("methodName", methodName);
            formData.add("pdfPath", "C:/folder/a.pdf"); //path to my pdf doc that needs to be sent to the server
            formData.add("textFile", "C:/folder/b.txt");
            Response response = webTarget.request().post(Entity.form(formData));
            String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

and the webservice is as follows:

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String createBooking(@PathParam("methodName") String methodName, 
            @FormParam("pdfPath") String pdfPath, 
            @FormParam("textFile") String textFile))
{
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
}
```

Comment: Can the webservice server access files on your machine? If so, you could send the name of the file. If not, you will probably have to upload the file to the webservice server so that it can access it directly.

Comment: How to know whether the server has access to the files on my machine or not? I am a newbie!

Comment: Then it does not. Look at it this way - I can post you a broken light fitting, you can fix it and post it back to me. If I just email you which light fitting in my house is broken, then unless you have my keys and address it's not going to get fixed. You have the same issue - sending your webserver the path to your file is entirely useless unless you have somehow exchanged a means of access to your computer prior to that. You need to end the entire file, the server will process it, then you can download it again.

Comment: P.S. If webservers could read arbitrary files from our computers we'd all be robbed blind in a matter of seconds...

Comment: @BoristheSpider, thank you for your example. You are right. I had the same concept and figured out it might not work that way. Can you tell me how to upload a file to the server? Do I provide a path and do the rest from the server?

Comment: Not sure why you accepted the answer you accepted, but it doesn't really answer the question. "_Do I provide a path and do the rest from the server?_" No. Back to our analogy; you have emailed me which light fitting is broken - how am I supposed to handle anything? You need to mail me _the light fitting_. Not its location.

Comment: Check the link in comments posted by sumit. http://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/jax-rs-resteasy-file-upload-httpclient-example/
I did not try it out yet but seems like the right way to go. What do you think, @BoristheSpider

Comment: @LeMe it's from 2013. I did not read further.

Comment: https://javatutorial.net/java-file-upload-rest-service
@BoristheSpider, how about this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approach to do that.

> **1-** If your machine and server are in same network and have shared resources then your server can directly access that file.
>
> **2-** This is most significant method. You first need to upload that file
>   to your server and then write that file on your server and do what you
>   want with that file.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide me with  relevant code on how to upload the file to the server? Do I send the path and allow the server to download? I am a bit lost here

Comment: @LeMe Put your web service controller code and client function then i will be able to  update that and server can not download file from your client

Comment: If you are using java rest service then refer this link **[link](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/)**

Comment: Let us know where that shared folder is, I have some malw... errr... very fine utilities to drop for your convenience there, you'll be thrilled I promise.

Comment: @LeMe i hope this will solved your problem. To give you full code is difficult but i can help you to understand the way. Just refer this example **http://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/jax-rs-resteasy-file-upload-httpclient-example/**